# Not getting user with correct credentials with asp.net identity and owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

I am doing custom authentication in mvc using `asp.net identity and owin` framework but unfortunately not getting user with correct credentials with below method:

```
 var user = UserManager.Find(email, HashedNewPassword);
```

I have stored my email and password like below in my database table:

```
Id      EmailAdress      Password
1       Abc@yahoo.com    123456
```

Right now I am doing like this but later on I will hash this password and store it in table. This is just for testing Microsoft owin framework.

But I am not getting user with this credentials:

```
Emaild Id:Abc@yahoo.com  
Password:123456.
```

This is my code:

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
        public class AuthenticationController : Controller
        {
            public AuthenticationController()
                : this(new UserManager<UserModel>(new UserStore(new MyEntities())))
            {
            }

            public AuthenticationController(UserManager<UserModel> userManager)
            {
                UserManager = userManager;
            }

            public UserManager<UserModel> UserManager { get; private set; }



            [HttpPost]
            [AllowAnonymous]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string email, string password, string returnUrl)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var user = UserManager.Find(email, password); //getting null here
                }
            }
        }

UserModel:

  public class UserModel : IUser
    {
        public string Id { get; private set; }
        public string UserName { get { return Email; } set { Email = value; } }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }


        public UserModel(string email, string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            Email = email;
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }

        public UserModel(Users dbUser)
        {
            if (dbUser == null)
                return;

            Id = dbUser.Id.ToString();
            Email = dbUser.EmailAddress;

            FirstName = dbUser.FirstName;
            LastName = dbUser.LastName;
        }
    }





   public class UserStore : IUserStore<UserModel>, IUserPasswordStore<UserModel>
        {
            public Task<UserModel> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    HttpContext.Current = _httpContext ?? HttpContext.Current;
                    var dbUser = GetDbUser(userName);
                    if (dbUser == null)
                        return null;
                    return new UserModel(dbUser);
                });
            }




            private Users GetDbUser(string userName)
            {
                using (var db = new MyEntities())
                {
                    return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailAddress.Equals(userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                }
            }


            public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(UserModel user)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    HttpContext.Current = _httpContext ?? HttpContext.Current;
                    var userObj = GetDbUser(user);

                    int len = userObj.Password.Length % 4;
                    //solved this error with below code :Invalid length for a Base-64 char array
                    if (len > 0) userObj.Password = userObj.Password.PadRight(userObj.Password.Length + (4 - len), '=');
                    return userObj.Password;  //sometimes progam gets stuck here on debugging
                });
            }


            private Users GetDbUser(UserModel user)
            {
                if (user.Id == null)
                    return null;
                return GetDbUser(Convert.ToInt32(user.Id));
            }

            private Users GetDbUser(int userId)
            {
                using (var db = new MyEntities())
                {
                    return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
                }
            }
        }
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're storing the password as plain text in the database? If that's the case, then that's your problem. You can't just choose to hash it later; Identity needs it hashed in order to match the password. This is how authentication works:

1. User submits username and password
2. Identity hashes submitted password
3. Identity looks up the user matching the submitted username and compares the password on that record with the hashed submitted password. If it matches, the user is signed in.

So, when Identity compares the hashed version of `123456` to the plain-text `123456`, it will never match. In order for it to match, the password saved in the DB must be hashed as well.

Comment: But basically we wont be giving any kind of registration as of now.we will be directly creating users from database to allow only some users to quickly login in to system.so how do i do this???

Comment: Even if you aren't allowing users to register directly, you should still provide some sort of admin from where you can create new users, where you can then hash the password that's set. Since Identity pretty much needs to be in charge of the hashing so that it can match it later when the user logs in, you'll need to handle it via the API Identity provides, rather than trying to just add records manually to the database.

Comment: But if you look at this method GetDbUser(user) of this GetPasswordHashAsync i am getting user but when i debug and control comes on this line return userObj.Password; then program get stuck.Why this is happening??

Comment: That's probably because you're spinning off a new thread, and probably blocking. You should never, never, like ever, manually create a thread like this in an MVC action context.

Comment: ok thanks.so can you suggest me some good changes in my methods??

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = UserManager.Find(email, password); //getting null here
```

I had a similar problem.
Your function return null, because this function must work with **UserName**.

1.

```
var user = UserManager.Find(UserName, password);
```

That is you input:
Login : MyLogin

password: 123123

e-mail: MyLogin@email.com

and this function work with login (UserName fiel on the table AspNetUserLogins)

You want to transfer

`var user = UserManager.Find(MyLogin@email.com, password);`

but actually it is transferred
`var user = UserManager.Find(MyLogin, password);`

**Attenction!** These are two different cells in the table

2. **Just create your user this and your default functions be work:**

`ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Year = model.Year };`